# Allowing similar tags or merged searches?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When posting a question and adding tags, users have the ability to create a tag.  This can lead to many similar tag interpretations.  Today we have tags for cluster-analysis, and findclusters, kernel, kernelstartup and so on, where a single tag for these may provide the user greater ability to find answers on a given subject.

Or an alternative to the above method would be when a user searches a tag they are presented with results from similar tags as a lower priority to their search results.

Comment: I agree with you that too many similar tags are likely to prove detrimental to searchability. But this problem is due in large part to incorrect usage of tags on the part of the asker--[tag:kernel-startup] being a prime example; IMO this tag should never have been used in the first place. If people fundamentally misunderstand the nature of their problem or the proper usage of particular tags, I don't think any automated system will be able to help them. Rather, that's why we need high-rep users who can exercise critical judgment and retag as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

First, this being a request for a network-wide feature, I would suggest you post it on the [main meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Apart from that, I'm not sure I understand exactly your suggestion. To me, the examples you give are good examples of questions needing retagging, and if the problem persists over time, tag synonyms being defined. This requires manual intervention, but somehow I suspect your approach also does: How would “related tags” be defined? This requires some user feedback, doesn't it? Or, if it is somehow automated, it would be error-prone.

Finally, I don't think people other than advanced users search by tag. If you search for  `[kernel] something` indeed will hide a post that was tagged [kernelstartup](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernelstartup), but you can also search for `kernel something`, which often works just as well!

Comment: Google automates their searches by keyword and in our case that's true also.  Clicking tags initiates searches, favorite tags do this automatically even for novice users.  If Feature requests must go to the main meta site...why do we have a tage for that? ;) Thanks for your feedback and help!

Comment: @RHall There are some things we can do here locally, such as deciding what tags to use and how to use them.  But features like the one you request can only be implemented by the programmers at SE, Inc., it would require modifying the software that all the SE sites are based on

Comment: @Szabolcs Got it!  Thanks!